# Alternative colloquial expressions for "I thought"

Tags: phrase-requests

When expressing how we misunderstand the others's expressions we often say "I thought ...". But, out of curiosity, I want to know are there any other expressions equivalent to the meaning of "I thought" and colloquial?

Comment: "seems to me..."

Comment: "I took you to mean ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always go for - ***"I was under the impression"***.

Per [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/under+the+impression):

> **Thinking, assuming, or believing something**, as in *I was under the impression that they were coming today*. This idiom often suggests
>   that the idea or belief one had is mistaken. [ Mid-1800s ]

Comment: Yes, thanks. I did not express what I intend clearly. I have made necessary revisions for my question. As a native speaker, I do not know whether or not an expression is colloquial or formal.